# Customizing Windows Forms (table)

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I have no clue if this is possible or not as I'm new to C#.  But is it possible to make a Windows Forms look like the picture?  Where you have a

1. gradient at top
2. alternating color rows
3. change the default text color
4. change the default highlight color
5. change the way the scroll bar looks

If so, are there tutorials for these someone can point me to?

Comment: Uh, yes, of course you can. The tutorials are just the basic Windows Forms stuff - go learn it.

Comment: All of this is possible however you will be better off asking several more specific questions, for example "How do I draw a gradient in Windows Forms?" and "How do I alternate row colours in a list box?".  Some of those questions will probably already have duplicate answers on StackOverflow, so research first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Gradient effects will take tedious paint task. You have some example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/8fceeaad-7698-4228-91f1-67964780c1d2)
2. Alternating Row Colors,

   > `datagridview1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor= Color.Blue;`
3. Change Text Color

   > `datagridview1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;`
4. Change Highlight Color

   > `datagridview1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Pink;
5. As far as I know scroll-bar will have the look of your current system theme and cant be change that easily unless you write your own code for it.

Comment: The link you gave for painting a gradient appears to be for WPF, not Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding skinning (gradients, custom scroll bar): WinForms are a wrapper around Win32 native controls. They were not designed with visual appearance customization in mind. It is possible but will require an awful lot of work: There is nothing comparable to CSS in WinForms.

An arguably easier alternative would be [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

Of course, the most straightforward might be to look for a 3rd party component such as [Krypton's DataGrid](http://componentfactory.com) (free).

Comment: I think you are somewhat overstating the effort needed to draw a gradient - there is no doubt that this is a lot easier in WPF, but its still perfectly possible in a Windows Forms application, you just need to draw the gradient yourself.

Comment: What about the scroll bar ;-)